# Question about books answer to estimating variance of block

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, experiment-design

The question is,

Suppose that a single factor experiment with four factors and six blocks is conducted and the error sum of squares is 500 and the sum of squares for the blocks is 250. The question asks to estimate $\hat \sigma^{2}$ and it gives the options of

25,25.5,35,37.5 and none of the above. It indicates the correct solution is none of the above.

What I thought:

$N=a*n=4*6=24$

so $N-a=20$ is the degrees of freedom for the error.

We also have $E[MSE]=\hat \sigma^{2}$ so I am  not sure why 25 would not be the immediate solution?

I also know that

$\hat \sigma_{b}^{2}=\frac{MSB-MSE}{a}$

which would imply $\hat \sigma_{b}^{2}=6.25$